# numpy: broadcasting ndarray of booleans

Tags: python, numpy

I have a situation in which I have an ndarray X of floats, let's say 100x10, and I want to look at some conditions on the first column and create a boolean ndarray B of shape 100x1. Then I want to use B as an index into X to pull out values where a True is located. However for each True in B I want to pull out the entire row of X. I thought this would work automatically, as B would be broadcast to a 100x10 shape. However it doesn't seem to work this way. Here's an example using 2x2 and 2x1 ndarrays.

```
a = np.array([True, False])
a.shape = (2,1)
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b.shape = (2,2)
print(a)
print(b)
print(b[a])
```

This prints

```
[[True]
 [False]]

[[ 1 2 ]
 [ 3 4 ]]

 [1]
```

I expected it to print `[1 2]`. Why doesn't the broadcasting work the way I expect?

Comment: just get rid of the line where you change a's shape ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for so-called "fancing indexing" are [detailed here](http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy-docs/reference/arrays.indexing.rst/#boolean). In particular, when the index, `obj`, is a NumPy array of dtype `bool`, `x[obj]`

> ... is always equivalent to (but faster than) x[obj.nonzero()]
>   where, as described above, obj.nonzero() returns a tuple (of length
>   obj.ndim) of integer index arrays showing the True elements of obj.

Since,

```
In [4]: a.nonzero()
Out[4]: (array([0]), array([0]))
```

`b[a]` is equivalent to `b[a.nonzero()]` which is

```
In [6]: b[(np.array([0]), np.array([0]))]
Out[6]: array([1])
In [7]: b[a]
Out[7]: array([1])
```

---

If you want to use a boolean array `a` to select *rows* of `b`, then, as Joran Beasley states, just keep `a` as a 1-dimensional boolean array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([True, False])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b.shape = (2,2)
print(b[a])    
# [[1 2]]
```

Comment: Hmm, well my array of booleans b is generated by something like the following: `b = a[:,1] < 0.5`. So it will be an ndarray of a single column. Is there a way to convert that to a 1-d array?

Comment: If `b` is of shape `(n, 1)`, then `np.squeeze(b)` will be of shape `(n,)` -- `np.squeeze` removes single-dimensional entries from the shape of the array.